# How to check if the decryption is correct?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I'm working on chat room that encrypt messages for more than one users and each user might have different encryption and key/password. The user's key won't work with all the message, therefore; return errors.

```
var message ="secret message";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, "Secret Passphrase");
try {
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase123").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    if (decrypted.length > 0) {
        alert(decrypted);
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
} catch(e) {
    alert("false");
}
```

I'm currently catching the error, but sometimes the decryption returns with jumbled up letters and symbols. The current way I'm doing this is not efficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: You're not currently using the same secret passphrase to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Seems like you are going about this wrong. If the message isn't supposed to be decrypted by a certain user, then don't *try* to decrypt it. That avoids any problems with attempted to decrypt with the wrong key and getting garbage. Figure out how to send messages with some data that tells you who it's for.

Comment: @ManoDestra: I think that was the point. The OP wants to figure out how, looking at `decrypted` to tell that it was decrypted with the wrong key.

Comment: @ManoDestra: I know. (: I did that on purpose as an example. I need a better way to deal with encryption keys that doesn't work.

Comment: If you insist on trying to decrypt messages with keys that might be wrong, then (and I'm not a security expert - you should talk to one maybe on http://security.stackexchange.com/) my naive suggestion would be to include a checksum with your message. Then you can calculate the checksum for the decoded message and check it. If it's wrong, then you don't have the right key.

Comment: @ Matt Burland:right, but that still doesn't really deal with the error/problem when the key is wrong, even if its sent to only one user.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve here. If you use the wrong password to decrypt, then your code is broken. And if the decrypted result does not parse to what you expect, then you will know immediately that it didn't work.

Comment: you should ask Bruce Schneier.

Comment: its a chat room with different users and different messages, and to avoid the user typing in a key every time a message is post, I have it so it automaticly does it for them. Like I said the broswer with return an error and sometime break down my code or cause the program to take longer to try to decode(lot longer). I'm jus looking for anther way to handle or check if the key is right.

Comment: who's Bruce Schneier?

Comment: @Danny You setup still doesn't make a lot of sense. If a user is encypting a message with their own key, then who the heck is it for? And if a message isn't intended for somebody then by far the best approach is *to not send it to them in the first place*. Nobody can break your encoding at all if they *don't actually have the message to start with*, so better would be to not broadcast messages in the first place. Security is a very complex subject and it is not generally a good idea to try and roll your own.

Comment: in the chat room, the message is group together, so third parties won't be able to tell the difference between each messages from different user. and the users will only be able to see the message that their key can decrypt.

Comment: So instead of including the user id with the message you include the group id and only attempt to decrypt if the user is a member of that group (so they have the relevant key). Else don't even attempt it.

Comment: Oh and, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier) is Bruce Schneier

Comment: yes. the encryption is an option or can sent private message(encrypted or not) or post thier message as them self or be anonymous. it all up them.

Comment: Oh and, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moxie_Marlinspike) is Moxie Marlinspike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is needed it authenticated encryption, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption).

Essentially HMAC the encrypted data with the encryption key and append the result to the encrypted data.

Prior to decryption HMAC the encrypted data with the decryption key and compare to the appended HMAC value. (Use a constant time comparison function.)

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea to split the key into an encryption key and a MAC key.

Comment: I think I kinda get it: the key(hashed) is add to the end of the encryption. and on decryption it check if the last numbers of values(depending on the key(hash)) to see if the value matches. (:

Answer (score 2):

Put a prefix at the beginning of each message, e.g.

```
encrypt("ABCD" + message);
```

Then when you decrypt, check if the result begins with `"ABCD"`.

This isn't foolproof, since it's possible that an incorrect decryption could have the same prefix, but it's very unlikely (make it longer to reduce the chance).

However, there's a security implication, since if someone knows that every message begins with the same prefix, it can help them analyze and try to break the encryption (similar to how you can use known letter frequencies when trying to break a simple Caesar cypher).

A slightly better method would be to generate a random string, and then put it in two places in the string before encrypting. Then check that they match.

```
random = random_string(10);
encrypt(random + message + random);
```

Then after decrypting, check if the first and last 10 characters match.

Comment: *"However, there's a security implication, since if someone knows that every message begins with the same prefix, it can help them analyze and try to break the encryption"*: This was a large part of how the allies broke the enigma code.

Comment: @MattBurland True, but I suspect the security of his chatroom isn't as important as German secrets, so who cares? And modern encryption algorithms are more complex than Enigma, so it may not help that much.

Comment: Essentially the "ABCD" is a crib. I get a list of frequent passwords. Use them to decrypt the first block and match "ABCD", I will have the data decrypted very quickly. Perhaps @Barmar is an NSA plant working to help create easily broken encryption. ;-)

Comment: @Barmar The point is that users have an expectation that when told that something is secure it is not trivial to break.

Comment: @zaph I've added another method using a random string.

Comment: @Barmar There are existing well vetted methods to authenticate, it is best to use them rather than inventing something new -- unless you are really a well known cryptographer, perhaps you are Moxie Marlinspike incognito?  ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break."

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, most of the time you'll get an error if the bytes don't fit neatly into `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8`.  But on occasion, like you said the user might get lucky (or unlucky) and submit a key that decrypts to valid `Utf8` bytes and it doesn't really know the difference.  I'd be curious to know how often this happens.

My solution would be to parse the decrypted string and look for a few 'indicators' that the message looks like a normal English sentence, instead of a random string of random characters.  First thing I would do would be to check for the number of spaces in the string.  This would probably be the single best indicator.

Comment: Thanks. "parse the message"? like checking the first few word for a phrase, does that make it a security issue?

Comment: @Daniel Patrick Perhaps a user is writing in Spanish or computer code or Hebrew or Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a security expert. You might consider asking a question on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for a better opinion (read their FAQ first), but:

1) You shouldn't be trying to decrypt a message with the wrong key in the first place. That's just not something that should be happening. If a message is intended for a particular user and was encrypted using their key then include in your message *who it's for* and on the receiving end check *if the message was for you*:

Sending:

```
var message = { user: 1122, body: encryptedMessage };
send(message);
```

Recieving:

```
if (message.user == myUserId) {
    decyptMessage(message.body);
} else {
    // this message isn't for you
}
```

2) If for some reason that doesn't work, then you would need to insert something in the message that you can use to confirm that it's decypted properly. A [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) would achieve this:

Sending:

```
var message = originalMessage + CalcChecksum(originalMessage);
send(encypt(message));
```

Recieving:

```
var decrypted = decrypt(message);
var msg = getTheBodyPartOfTheMessage(decrypted);
var chk = getTheChecksumPartOfTheMessage(decrypted);
if (chk == CalcChecksum(msg) {
    // this is a good message
} else {
    // this message isn't for you
}
```

You can used a fixed length checksum so that, say, the last two characters are always the checksum or you could use some character (that won't otherwise appear) as a delimiter.

I like the checksum better than the idea of prefixing (or postfixing) some known string to every message because the checksum will be different for each message (well, not quite - but you won't be able to predict it).

Comment: There are existing well vetted methods to authenticate, it is best to use them rather than inventing something new.

Comment: @zaph: I thought I'd made it perfectly clear that I was not an expert and pointed the OP to a resource that would be better suited. And my first suggestion is absolutely NOT inventing new method to authenticate, it's about directing the message to the right recipient in the first place.

Comment: Yet you present a method using checksums (how quaint) you make up. Keep in mind that the encryption must also protect against an attacker. A checksum on a short message will leak information.