# AES collision with random IV

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, php-openssl

**The Hypothesis**: my encryption/decryption mechanism malfunctioned in such a way that integer plaintext message Pi1 was encrypted and got later decrypted into an integer plaintext Pi2.

**The technical circumstance**: I use AES 128-bit with random IV for encryption/decryption. The key is changed everyday. I use openssl php extension.

**The actual problem**: I encrypted Pi1, but then I decrypted it to Pi2. Those are numbers around 120000 and 120100 respectively. I do not know whether key(somedayago) or key(today) was used to decrypt the message.

**The question**: is it possible that

1. Pi1 encrypted with k was decrypted using k to Pi2? or
2. Pi1 encrypted with k(today-n) was decrypted using k(today) to Pi2?

Thanks

Comment: technically, decryption will always be successful. enc/dec are just mathematical operations, and you'll always get a result out, even if the key was wrong. the result will almost certainly be garbage, but it'll be a valid outcome of the "math" performed by the decryption function. if AES suffered from such trivial collisions, then it would have to be immediately blacklisted and never used again, because it'd be no better than a cereal box decoder ring.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place for this question.

Comment: To 1: No, not at all. But depending on how the IV is managed, there could still be differences. To 2: Yes, that's possible, but sometimes (255 in 256 cases) you get a padding exception if this is done properly.

Comment: If you need to know if the decryption was successful, meaning the same as what was encrypted use authenticated encryption. See this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37664062/451475) for more details on authenticated encryption.

Comment: @Barmar Crypto.stackexchange.com is also available. When posting there post as many details as possible, e.g. mode of operation, padding mode etc.